# How do you edit an embed's Thumbnail in Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I can't seem to find out how to edit an embed's thumbnail? Could anyone help?

What I've tried:

```
const blaBla = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setThumbnail("some link that I added here");

message.channel.fetchMessage("My_Message_ID)")
    .then(message => message.edit(blaBla));
```

After doing that, and executing that code, the message doesn't update, any reason why?

Comment: You use it in the same channel wich your message posted?

Comment: @Cipher Yup~ I tried that :(

Comment: Promisse message returns message ?

Answer (score -1):

If the your discord.js version is v12.0 you should do it this way

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch({around: "352292052538753025", limit: 1})
  .then(messages => {
    messages.first().edit("This fetched message was edited");
  });
```

Comment: `message.channel.messages.fetch('352292052538753025').then(m => m.edit(...))`